# How can you update and create a new row in Laravel from a JSON object with relationships?

Tags: php, laravel

I started using Laravel yesterday, the ORM seems powerful. Does it have any way of updating rows in related models? This is what I tried:

Step 1: Generate a JSON object with the exact structure the database has. The JSON object has certain fields that are subarrays which represent relationships in the database.

Step 2: Send the JSON object via POST to Laravel for processing, here it gets tricky:
I can change the JSON object into an array first

```
$array = (array) $JSONobject;
```

Now I need to update, I would expect this to work:

```
Product::update($JSONobject->id,$array);
```

But because the array has subarrays, the update SQL that is executed cannot find the sub-array column in the table, it should instead look for the associated table. Can this be done? Or do I have to call the other models as well?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is something that Eloquent does not handle for you. The array that you supply to the `update()` method should contain columns only for, in your case, the `Product` model. You might try something like this to update relations. This is all off the top of my head and is by no means tested. Take it with a grain of salt.

```
$update = (array) $JSONobject;

$relations = [];

foreach ($update as $column => $value)
{
    // If the value is an array then this is actually a relation. Add it to the
    // relations array and remove it from the update array.
    if (is_array($value))
    {
        $relations[$column] = $value;

        unset($update[$column]);
    }
}

// Get the product from the database so we can then update it and update any of the
// the products relations.
$product = Product::find($update['id']);

$product->update($update);

foreach ($relations as $relation => $update)
{
    $product->{$relation}()->update($update);
}
```

The above code assumes that the key for your nested relation arrays is the name of the relation (method name used in your model). You could probably wrap this up in a method on your `Product` model. Then just call something like `Product::updateRecursively($JSONobject);` I'm terrible with names but you get the idea.

This probably won't work with more complex relations either. You'd have to take it a few steps further for things like many to many (or probably even one to many).